# Retrieving data from Firebase into recyclerView doesn't show me any data from the Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to read data from my Firebase Database into RecyclerView but when i run the program and open the activity which is suppose to show the data, it doesn't show me anything and also i got no error in Android Studio.

I have tried every solution on the internet but nothing works

this is my Adapter

```
package com.example.rsolveapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterDescRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDescRecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Description> daftarBarang;
private Context context;

public AdapterDescRecyclerView(ArrayList<Description> barangs, Context ctx){

    daftarBarang = barangs;
    context = ctx;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView tvTitle;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_namabarang);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_job, parent, false);
    // mengeset ukuran view, margin, padding, dan parameter layout lainnya
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final String name = daftarBarang.get(position).getDescription();
    holder.tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    holder.tvTitle.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.tvTitle.setText(name);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return daftarBarang.size();
}
}
```

this is my activity for showing the data

```
package com.example.rsolveapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;





public class RsolverMatch extends AppCompatActivity{


private DatabaseReference database;
private RecyclerView rvView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<Description> daftarBarang;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.rsolvermatch);


    rvView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
    rvView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    database.child("description").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            daftarBarang = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Description description = noteDataSnapshot.getValue(Description.class);
                description.setKey(noteDataSnapshot.getKey());


                daftarBarang.add(description);
            }


            adapter = new AdapterDescRecyclerView(daftarBarang, RsolverMatch.this);
            rvView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            System.out.println(databaseError.getDetails()+" "+databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

public static Intent getActIntent(Activity activity){
    return new Intent(activity, RsolverMatch.class);
}
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the Firebase Database

[Screenshot of Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BL6l.png)

This is my Desciption.java (Class)

```
package com.example.rsolveapp;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Description implements Serializable{
private String description;
private String day, sHour, sMin, eHour, eMin;
private String key;

public Description(){

}

public String getKey(){
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key){
    this.key=key;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description=description;
}

public String getDay(){
    return day;
}

public void setDay(String day){
    this.day=day;
}

public String getsHour(){
    return sHour;
}

public void setsHour(String sHour){
    this.sHour=sHour;
}

public String getsMin(){
    return sMin;
}

public void setsMin(String sMin){
    this.sMin=sMin;
}

public String geteHour(){
    return eHour;
}

public void seteHour(String eHour){
    this.eHour=eHour;
}

public String geteMin(){
    return eMin;
}

public void seteMin(String eMin){
    this.eMin=eMin;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return " "+description+"/n"+
            " "+day+"/n"+
            " "+sHour+"/n"+
            " "+sMin+"/n"+
            " "+eHour+"/n"+
            " "+eMin;
}

public Description(String desc, String dayz, String startH, String startM, String endH, String endM){
    description=desc;
    day=dayz;
    sHour=startH;
    sMin=startM;
    eHour=endH;
    eMin=endM;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your database structure and stacktrace

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I couldn't put the JSON file because there is no attachment for it, i hope the screenshot can explain it otherwise.

Comment: @Ashish already edited a screenshot of the database structure, thank you for pointing it out. For the meantime i cannot show the stacktrace due to technical issues, will add it later after the issue can be solved.

Comment: @BryanRatin Please also add the content of your `Description` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo Description.java (Class) has been added

Comment: @BryanRatin If you try to use the following line of code `Log.d(TAG, description);` inside `onDataChange()` method, is it something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo Update : after i enable the stacktrace the data that i wanted to display appeared, is this supposed to happen? Or maybe stacktrace just put it on debug mode?

Comment: @AlexMamo and about the logcat, i haven't tried it.

Comment: @BryanRatin Try it and tell me if it works.

Comment: @AlexMamo it give me error "cannot resolve symbol description"

Comment: Show us the entire error. A screenshot might be also useful.

Comment: @AlexMamo the error is no longer exists after adding stacktrace command, thank you sir